# How to create user defined conditional statements in c?

Tags: c

I have two stacks s1 and s2 with numbers stored in them.

I have a function(say comp) which compares the numerical values of s1 and s2.

I want to know if it is possible to modify the function so that I can use the conditional statements like:

```
If(s1>s2){statememts}
```

The naive idea to convert the stacks to their numerical values and then comparing, wont work for me as the stacks contain large numbers(around 30 digits) and the default data type overflows.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Because there he will have to post some non-working code or be violently downvoted & he may not have any code yet as he seems to be looking for advice on how to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

What you need for that is called operator overloading, which is not supported in C. See the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c

You could write it in C++ though ...

Comment: Of write your own functions greater(s1, s2), etc